# OctoberCMS Partials sharing variables life cycle

Tags: components, octobercms, partials

I'm new in October CMS and I try to develop some components and these components have more than one page. I include every page as a partial in the default.htm file with an if condition depends on the type property of the page.

```html
{% set type = __SELF__.property('type') %}
{% if type == 'y' %}
{% partial 'x::yy' %}
{% elseif type == 'x' %}
{% partial 'x::xx' %}
```

the problem is when I have a collection of items in one page and send id of one of the items to another ajax handler and want to retrieve full info of the item, I can't pass it to next page because of the page cycle in October CMS.for example :

```html
// firstpage
{% set posts = __SELF__.posts %}
{%for post in posts%}
<button data-request="handlerX" data-request-data="id: {{post.id}}">
{%endfor%}


//hanlerX
public function onHanldlerX(){
  $post = $this->post = POST::where('id',post("id"))->first();
  return redirect()->to('/my-posts/'.$post->slug);
}

//nextpage -> my-posts/$post->slug
// post informations is unavailible
```

what's the best way for these type of components?
Is It the right way for this?
how can I send variables to view after the OnRun method in components?

Comment: I recommend you ask for help on the slack, it'll be easier to have a back and forth about the issue you're having and then the final answer can be summarized here.

Comment: on nextpage `my-posts/$post->slug` you have `:slug` param so from it you again need to find post from URL and in component in `onRun` you can find $post from slug and pass it again